# Convert sentence of strings to lowercase

Tags: c

could someone tell me why am i not getting converted my entire sentence to lowercase? Just the first string untill it finds space?
Ive got

```
void uppertolower(char *STR)
for(unsigned int i =0;i<=strlen(sentence);i++) 
{
    if(*STR>='A' && *STR<='Z')
    {
        *STR=*STR+32;
        STR++;
    }
}
```

This code makes from sentence like HEllo WOrld

Sencte that looks like: hello WOrld

My question is what should i add or change to make the whole HEllo WOrld in lowercase?

Comment: Please move `STR++;` outside the conditional block, it should always be advanced, whether or not the character was upper case.

Comment: I think `sentence` should be `STR` although the example is incomplete, also lacking a pair of `{` braces `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments say:
What is this `sentence`? your *i* should go from *0* to *strlen(STR)* EXCLUSIVELY
meaning

> //  "<"  Not  "<="  or you could segfault in more complex programs.
>
> for (int i = 0; i < strlen(STR); i++)

In your example, the reason why it's not converting the whole sentence is because your pointer `STR` will only be incremented when the condition is met, it means that it will get stuck on the first small letter your find, so it's actually stuck on the letter `l` and not on the space.

To put it all together.

```
void uppertolower(char *STR)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(STR); i++) 
    {
       if (*STR >= 'A' && *STR <= 'Z')
       {
           *STR = *STR + 32;
       }
       STR++;
    }
}
```

If you're intereset, another way to do it is this:

```
void uppertolower(char *STR)
{
    while (*STR)  // Same as while (*STR != '\0')
    {
       if (*STR >= 'A' && *STR <= 'Z')
       {
           *STR = *STR + 32;
       }
       STR++;
    }
}
```

Or like this

```
void uppertolower(char *STR)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(STR); i++)
    {
       if (STR[i] >= 'A' && STR[i] <= 'Z')
       {
           STR[i] = STR[i] + 32;
       }
    }
}
```

And if you are learning how to code in c, please checkout the `Recommended C Style and Coding Standards.` (or at least the naming conventions).
https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/cstyle.html#N103FD